# do snprintf() internally call memset() or similar?

Tags: c, arrays, printf, memset

I'm cognizant of using `snprintf()` in lieu of `sprintf()` for safety. However, I always do `memset()` on buffer used by `snprintf()`. I saw some codes using the function without `memset()`. And, it works as expected. I mean there is no overwriting on the buffer. Let me exemplify,

```
char str[100];
snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "stackoverflow %zu", sizeof(str));
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", str);

snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "soner");
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", str);
```

Until now, I thought that the code would print `soneroverflow 100` that's why I used `memset()`. Nevertheless, it prints `soner`. How is it done underhood? By the way, same thing is applied for `sprintf()`.

Comment: You don't need to do anything with you buffer prior to calling `sprintf` or `snprintf`. You don't call `memset` either before using `strcpy`, do you?

Comment: @snr The reason is explained in the answer below.

Comment: Strange question for someone with >3k of reputation and lots of answers to C tagged questions.

Comment: @Jabberwocky <  There were some points I overlooked and realize later on. It may be not important so much, but I engage in concurrent programming with signals nowadays to learn. Small things sometimes result in big results.

Comment: Perhaps you're confusing with `strncpy()` - which doesn't write a NUL if it fills the output buffer.

Comment: @TobySpeight < Thanks indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/):

> A terminating null character is automatically appended after the content written.

If you were to inspect the buffer, you would find

```
{ 's', 'o', 'n', 'e', 'r', '\0', 'v', 'e', 'r', /* ... */ }
```

Comment: @snr _sprintf doesn't put null terminator_: if this is the case, then either your implementation of `sprintf` is broken, or your progam did something bad beforehand leading to undefined behaviour. Please edit your question and post a [mcve].

Comment: @Jabberwocky it is cuz lack of my knowledge, sprintf also is null terminated.

Comment: @snr `sprintf` and `snprintf` are very similar, both do `NUL` terminate the string.